snowflake streaming key pair authentication fail with encrypted key
I am using the snowflake streaming API SDK to connect to snowflake using key pair authentication mechanism with encrypted keys.
Used following commands to generate encrypted keys:-
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 des3 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8
openssl rsa -in rsa_key.p8 -pubout -out rsa_key.pub
I created snowflake streaming client and try to connect using the above generated encrypted keys. The code is as following :-
Properties streamingClientProperties = new Properties();
streamingClientProperties.setProperty("user", "myUser");
streamingClientProperties.setProperty("url", "https://******.snowflakecomputing.com:443");
streamingClientProperties.put("private_key_path", "./rsa_key.p8");
streamingClientProperties.put("private_key_passphrase", "pass");
streamingClientProperties.setProperty("role", "ACCOUNTADMIN");
streamingClientProperties.setProperty("warehouse", "myWarehouse");


SnowflakeStreamingClient client = SnowflakeStreamingIngestClientFactory.builder(handlerProperties.clientName())
         .setProperties(handlerProperties.ingestClientProperties()).build();

But still getting error connecting to snowflake server:-
Caused by: net.snowflake.ingest.internal.org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13 not available: Wrong algorithm: DES
ede or TripleDES required
I am new to snowflake streaming. Please help.
